# How to store whole datastore entity in Google appengine memcache using JAVA so that it will be accessible across sessions

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, memcached, datastore

Currently at every system login I am fetching entire customer entity from google appengine datastore and using it in current session. Since number of records are in thousands, my google billing is increasing due to read operations.
So idea to reduce read operations from datastore is to store entity in memcache.
Just guide me how can I store whole entity in memcache using java code and how to read and update it through memcache.

Not tried anything yet. Need guidelines to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Can you check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/memcache/using) and [Article](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/memcache-basics-on-google-app-engine/).